# phpoffice can´t read xml inside xls

Tags: php, xml, xls, phpoffice

I need to create a script to read XLS and insert into mysql, so I decide to use phpoffice to do it.

The problem comes when inside this xls is a XML and phpoffice can´t read this row.

For example, if you try to read a xls with this rows:

```
January

<Febrary>

March
```

The output only shows you

```
January

March
```

**Note: there is a blank row between January an March but I´m having problems to show with this wysiwyg.**

Can someone tell me how can I Read this XML inside the XLS?

***I think the problem is when there is a word between"<" and ">" in a row, but I don´t know how to solve it.***

Thank´s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not PHPOffice that's causing any problem..... it's your lack of understanding of html markup.

You're echoing this to a browser..... and a browser treats `<` as a special character..... use [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to convert those specia 
characters to html entities before displaying it in your browser